# Multi-select query for MongoDB in JasperReports

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports

does anyone know a way to accomplish a multi select query when querying mongodb in JasperReport. In SQL there is the $X parameter, but I have not managed to find anything similar in the JasperReports MongoDB query language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by filtering out the non-selected items out using a filter expression in the report by checking every tuple from the field variable against the collection parameter like this:

```
<filterExpression><![CDATA[$P{date_id}.contains($F{date_id})]]></filterExpression>
```